# Deploying multiple rails applications on a single domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner Ruby on Rails developer.

So far I have created several rails applications on my computer localhost.  Now, I want to deploy those applications to a professional server.

I only have one domain and I was wondering if I can deploy multiple rails applications on a single domain?

If yes, what is the best way to do it?
Should I put every application in a folder?

And does the server need a specific requirement?

thanks,

Oded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use a subdomain for each application. So app1.yourdomain.com would point to application 1, app2.yourdomain.com would point to application 2, and so on.

Comment: This is the way Heroku does it, which encourages me that it's the right solution.